# Return elements list of list prologs

Tags: list, prolog, head

How to return all the elements of a list of lists in Prolog:

That's my code:

```
treturn_list_members([[Head|_]|Lists], Head).
treturn_list_members([[_|T]|Lists], Head):- return_list_members([T|Lists], Head).
```

When I execute, it only return the elem of the first list.

```
?- treturn_list_members([[12,3],[45,6],[11,90]],L).
L = 12 ;
L = 3 ;
false.
```

Comment: This is Prolog, so define what it means to be a member. Don't think of it imperatively as "return a list of members". Rather, define what it means to be a member. One of the following would be true: `is_a_member(E, [List|Lists]) :- member(E, List).` or `is_a_member(E, [_|Lists]) :- is_a_member(E, Lists).` If you're not allowed to use `member/2`, then roll your own, as it's fairly trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Rather use a better name.  "Returning" means that you operationalize this relation. But it suffices to say what the arguments are:

```
listoflist_member(Xss, X) :-
   member(Xs, Xss),
   member(X, Xs).
```